# Difference between FPM and WSGI

Tags: python, fastcgi, wsgi, php

Here is what I understand thus far.

PHP-FPM and WSGI are layers upon FastCGI?

So would it be right to say that WSGI is Python's FPM?

Answer (score 3):

WSGI is not actually a layer on FastCGI, but a specification for writing Python web applications that is sufficiently generic that it may attach to many web servers or adapters which in turn may speak to many other technologies, *including* FastCGI.  But FastCGI itself, which is a protocol for a web server to connect to a long-running process, need not be involved at all in a WSGI installation—e.g. the `mod_wsgi` Apache module, which exposes WSGI to your Python application directly from Apache and does not require you to run a separate long-running process.

WSGI is defined in [PEP 333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/).  A simple application, taken from that specification, looks like this:

```
def simple_app(environ, start_response):
    """Simplest possible application object"""
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return ['Hello world!\n']
```

Comment: so with WSGI protocol you can make a server uses FastCGI?

Comment: Sorry, I realize I was unclear about that bit.  I've edited my answer.  Writing to WSGI does not in itself give you the ability to attach to a server that supports FastCGI, but you can use a server that supports WSGI and speaks FastCGI to another server to accomplish this, such as one found in flup: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flup

Comment: there is no modification, i thought wsgi was a protocol that uses fastcgi (keep python process running and not run it every time a request comes)

Comment: Sorry, I must not have hit "save."  I re-edited just now.  A WSGI-based application can indeed remain running and serve many requests, but it does so managed by the server that speaks WSGI to it.  FastCGI is not involved *unless* the WSGI server is in turn speaking FastCGI to another web server.

Comment: sorry but i still dont get the idea, both uses long runnig listening process? and php-fpm an alternative PHP FastCGI implementation with some additional features, so i said that WSGI maybe a Python FastCGI implementation too?